# In bash, how to use a variable as part of the name of another variable?

Tags: bash, variables

Just a simple question

I have some arrays:

```
array_0=(1 2 3) 
array_1=(1 2 3) 
.......
```

I have a variable a:

```
 a=0
 echo ${array_"$a"[0]}
```

Got a bad substitution error. Does anyone know the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_0=(1 2 3)
array_1=(4 5 6)
array_2=(7 8 9)
for a in {0..2} ; do
  for i in {0..2} ; do
    eval 'echo ${'"array_$a[$i]"'}'
  done
done
```

Vaughn Cato's syntax is slightly more verbose, but the `echo` statement itself is more decipherable. You replace the inner part of the double `for` loop with these two lines:

```
    array_a=array_$a[$i]
    echo ${!array_a}
```

Comment: Do you know what if a itself is an array. For example, I replace $a with ${array_2[$j]}

Comment: @HaoShen: There should be no problem doing that, for either solution.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot. I just got stuck. What if I want to assign the result to a variable. For example,eval 'result=${'"array_$a[$i]"'}'. It doesn't work... Sorry for my continuous naive question...

Comment: You can, for example, surround the `eval` (the one with the `echo`) with `$()`, and assign that to a variable. With Vaughn's solution, you just assign `${!array_a}` to a variable.

Comment: Thank you. Actually eval 'result=${'"array_$a[$i]"'}' works. It's my mistake

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is to use this syntax:

```
array_a=array_$a[0]
echo ${!array_a}
```

The `!` as the first character indicates that you want to use an extra level of indirection by evaluating the variable and then using the result as the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`

```
echo $(eval echo \${array_$a[0]})
```

Note that I had to put a backslash in front of the first dollar sign to prevent the shell from interpolating that.

Needless to say, the whole purpose of arrays is to allow you to do this type of *variable interpolation* without all the fuss and bother of echoing evals like I had to do when I needed arrays with the original Bourne shell.